# Save a file to shared folder in google drive

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-api, google-drive-api

I would like to save a file into a folder shared in Google drive with me from another email id.

How can I access the email id associated with a shared folder?

How can I save the file to that specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the Manage Sharing [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-sharing):

> Access to files & folders is determined by an access control list
>   (ACL). An ACL is a list of permissions that determine whether or not
>   users can perform actions on a file such as read or write. See the
>   [permissions guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-permissions) for additional details about permissions and roles
>   along with the reference guide.

Permissions can be granted to a `role` and `additionalRoles` field. You can also determine the effective roles and use `teamDrivePermissionDetails` field. You can change the assigned role by using `permission.update` method. And use `permission.insert` to grant additional permissions to user, group, or domain.